# Is this file closed after open(file_name, 'r').read() in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I know we don't need to explicitly call the close() method by using the with statement like this

```py
with open("test.txt", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
   # perform file operations
```

But is this file is properly closed in this way:

```py
text = open(file_name, 'r').read()
```

Comment: No, if you don't use the context manager (`with` block) then the file is not automatically closed at the end of the statement

Comment: But if you do that in a function and `text` is a local variable, when the function returns, `text` goes out of scope. At some point after that, `text` will be garbage collected and the file will get closed just before that. That is why failing to call `close()` sometimes appears to do no harm. Best not to rely on that, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, the code you show will leave the open file handle dangling.

The `with open` context manager has the additional benefit of being resilient to errors, i.e. it will always close the file handle even if the code in the block throws an exception, for example.